# Powershell MSUtil.LogQuery not closing SQL connection

Tags: powershell, iis, logparser

I've written a PowerShell scrip that iterates through a large number of IIS W3C logfiles and inserts the values into a MSSQL database.

```
Set-Variable -Name "UnprocessedDir" -Value "X:\files" -Description "Folder for unprocessed log files" Scope Script
Set-Variable -Name "InputObject" -Value (New-Object -comObject MSUtil.LogQuery.IISW3CInputFormat) -Description "Log Parser input COM object" -Scope Script
Set-Variable -Name "OutputObject" -Value (New-Object -comObject MSUtil.LogQuery.SQLOutputFormat) -Description "Log Parser output COM object" -Scope Script
    $OutputObject.clearTable = $false
    $OutputObject.createTable = $false
    $OutputObject.database = "Database_Name"
    $OutputObject.driver = "SQL Server"
    $OutputObject.dsn = "DSN_Name"
    $OutputObject.fixColNames = $true
    $OutputObject.ignoreIdCols = $true
    $OutputObject.ignoreMinWarns = $true
    $OutputObject.maxStrFieldLen = 511
    $OutputObject.oConnString = $null
    $OutputObject.password = $null
    $OutputObject.server = "sqlserver.domain.com\INSTANCENAME"
    $OutputObject.transactionRowCount = 5000
    $OutputObject.username = $null

    Set-Variable -Name "IISLogs" -Value @(Get-ChildItem -Path $UnprocessedDir -Recurse -File) -Description "Array of files to be imported into SQL" -Scope Script
    Set-Variable -Name "LPComObj" -Value (New-Object -com MSUtil.LogQuery) -Description "COM Object used to import Log Parser records into MSSQL" -Scope Script
    Write-Output "$(Get-ISOTimeStamp) Beginning SQL import. $($IISLogs.Count) Files to be imported"

    $IISLogs | ForEach-Object { $loop = 0 } {
        Set-Variable -Name "SubDir" -Value $(($_.FullName).Split('\')[-2]) -Description "Subdirectory where log file is located" -Scope Script
        Set-Variable -Name "LogType" -Value $(($_.FullName).Split('\')[-3]) -Description "Type of log being imported" -Scope Script
        Set-Variable -Name "ServerName" -Value $(($_.FullName).Split('\')[-4]) -Description "ServerName of file being imported" -Scope Script
        Set-Variable -Name "LPQuery" -Description "Query to use in Log Parser" -Scope Script -Value @"
SELECT
-- FIELDS   LogFilename,LogRow,date,time,c-ip,cs-username,s-sitename,s-computername,s-ip,s-port,cs-method,cs-uri-stem,cs-uri-query,sc-status,sc-substatus,sc-win32-status,sc-bytes,cs-bytes,time-taken,cs-version,cs-host,cs(User-Agent),cs(Cookie),cs(Referer),s-event,s-process-type,s-user-time,s-kernel-time,s-page-faults,s-total-procs,s-active-procs,s-stopped-procs
-- STANDARD FIELDS date,time,s-ip,cs-method,cs-uri-stem,cs-uri-query,s-port,cs-username,c-ip,cs(User-Agent),cs(Referer),sc-status,sc-substatus,sc-win32-status,time-taken

    '$($ServerName)' as [servername],
    '$($_.Name)' as [filename],
    LogRow AS [row],
    '$($LogType)' as [logtype],
    TO_TIMESTAMP(date,time) AS [timestamp],
    [s-ip],
    [cs-method],
    [cs-uri-stem],
    [cs-uri-query],
    TO_INT([s-port]),
    [cs-username],
    [c-ip],
    [cs(User-Agent)],
    [cs(Referer)],
    TO_INT([sc-status]),
    TO_INT([sc-substatus]),
    TO_INT([sc-win32-status]),
    TO_INT([time-taken]),
    0 AS lock

INTO IIS_W3C

FROM '$($_.FullName)'
"@
        Set-Variable -Name "LPResult" -Value ($LPComObj.ExecuteBatch($LPQuery, $InputObject, $OutputObject)) -Description "IIS Log File imported into SQL" -Scope Script

        If ($LPResult -eq $false)
        {

            Write-Output "$(Get-ISOTimeStamp) Data imported from `"$($_.FullName)`""
            Set-Variable -Name "loop" -Value ($loop + 1) -Description "Increase loop iteration Count" -Scope Script
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Output "$(Get-ISOTimeStamp) Log Parser returned errors importing `"$($_.FullName)`""
            Throw "$(Get-ISOTimeStamp) Log Parser returned errors importing `"$($_.FullName)`""
        }
    }
```

The number of logs I'm importing is tens of thousands; the code above works spectacularly for a few hundred files, but after a few hours, it crashes. From what I can tell, it looks like every iteration of the `ForEach-Object` loop creates a new SQL TCP connection which is not terminated at the end of the loop.

I've tried creating the `$LPComObj` both within and outside of the loop. I've tried `Remove-Variable`. I've tried some generic commands like `$LPComObj.Close()`, `.Remove()`, `.Quit()`, etc. The `MSUtil.LogQuery` method itself does not seem to contain any methods to close the SQL TCP connection, and as the script is running, I can see more and more TCP connections piling up. I tried a few things using `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::` to release/remove the COM object, but none of them closed the TCP connection. Even closing the PowerShell session doesn't kill the connection.

The only way I was able to do this is by hunting down and finding the `dllhost.exe`" process that was using the ports and killing it. But from within the script, there isn't a clean way to get the PID of the offending `dllhost.exe` process. (Trying to kludge some variant of `Get-Process | Stop-Process` might work, but would add *a lot* of time to the execution of the script.)

What other ways might I be able to work around this problem?

Comment: I believe the only way to cause the connection to be closed is to force a destruction of the LogQuery and the InputFormat objects. I'm not too familiar with Powershell's COM integration, but I believe forcing references to these objects to null and kicking off the garbage collector could work.

Comment: I've tried `Clear-Item`, `Remove-Variable` as well as `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::CleanupUnusedObjectsInCurrentContext()`, `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($LPComObj)`, `[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($LPComObj)`, and `[System.GC]::Collect()`. I've also set the variable to `$NULL` and tried all of the above, and still no dice. I'm very open to trying other things, though. The `ReleaseComObject` did appear to kill the object, but the SQL connections are still open.